# Boto3 Service Catalog ProvisionProduct - Launch Path and ProductID not found

Tags: python, boto3, aws-service-catalog

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sc = boto3.client('servicecatalog')
    sc.provision_product(ProductId='prod-xyz1234', 
                         ProvisionedProductName='name of my provisioned ec2', 
                         ProvisioningArtifactID='foo',
                         ProvisioningParameters=[
                             {
                                 'Key': 'InstanceType',
                                 'Value': 't2.micro'
                             },
                             ....
```

I keep getting error for no launch paths

ResourceNotFoundException: An Error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling ProvisionProduct operation: No launch paths found for resource: *prod-xyz1234*

I also tried to do `sc.list_launch_paths(ProductId='prod-xyz1234'` and got no launch paths found for resource: *prod-xyz1234*